# Cakephp 3 routing with language

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I have the following urls:
a)

- www.example.com/en/pages/index
- www.example.com/fr/pages/index

b)

- www.example.com/en/users/users/profile (using CakeDC/Users)
- www.example.com/fr/users/users/profile (using CakeDC/Users)

For a), how can I use $this->Url->Build() function to create such a link?

For b), how can I convert these two links to the format like this:

- www.example.com/en/profile
- www.example.com/fr/profile

Comment: I think that's answers your question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365260/cakephp-3-routing-with-language-parameter

Comment: For b) situaction, it doesn't work.