# cakephp 3 parameter url

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I would like to know how is possible that if someone write a not existent link returns error in cakephp 3.

Example:

I have an action called test inside controller calle first.

Into my routing file I have declared language in this way inside `scope`:

```
  $lang = 'it|en';
  $routes->connect('/', ['language' => 'it', 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index', 'index'],
    ['language' => $lang]);

$routes->connect(
    '/:language/:controller',
    ['action' => 'index'],
    ['language' => $lang]
);

$routes->connect(
    '/:language/:controller/:action',
    ['language' => $lang]
);
```

So i expected that with this routing system if someone write inside the url:

```
`http://www.myownsite.it/languagenotexist/first/test` returns error, but take `languagenotexist` as a language but lang are only: 'it|en'.
```

How can I return error if the parameter language isn't it or en as I have declared in route file?

This need to work:

`http://www.myownsite.it/it/first/test`

Or

`http://www.myownsite.it/en/first/test`

This need to return error like 404 for example:

`http://www.myownsite.it/languagenotexist/first/test`

Or

`http://www.myownsite.it/es/first/test`

Because parameter language isn't it or en

Routing table:

```
pages:index         | /                              | {"language":"it","controller":"Pages","action":"index","0":"index","plugin":null}    |
| _controller:index   | /:language/:controller         | {"action":"index","plugin":null}                                                     |
| _controller:_action | /:language/:controller/:action | {"language":"it|en","action":"index","plugin":null}
```

Comment: I would suspect that you have connected more routes than you are showing here!?

Comment: I have make an example to understand the logic of the system. Other routes are similar and declared in the same method

Comment: I have removed the other routes to be sure... But the problem is always the same @ndm , now routes in this question are the same into my site

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are still other routes connected that are catching your non-language element url. Check `bin/cake routes`.

Comment: Inside bin/cake there isn't routes, I retrieve an error:  Shell class for "Routes" could not be found. in [/Users/alessandrominoccheri/Sites/mysite/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 282] @ndm

Comment: It's available as of CakePHP 3.1, and basically just outputs `Router::routes()` in a tabelish fashion.

Comment: I have update cakephp core and I have update my question with routing table @ndm

Comment: Ugh... I overlooked your last routes parameter order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp 3 routing with language parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365260/cakephp-3-routing-with-language-parameter)

Comment: So what is the solution for my problem? I have already seen the other question but I don't understand how to fix my problem. Can you help me please? @ndm

Comment: Just like in the duplicate, you are passing the options in the wrong argument, they should be passed as the third one, not the second one, the second needs to be an empty array if you want to skip it.

Comment: Ok! I have understood! And now it works like a charm! Thanks @ndm