# PHP fake url, complex .htaccess rewrite_mod

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I have real a lot about **CakePHP**, and php **rewrite_mod**, but i m so much confused about how to use it as i don't have knowledge about regex.
how can i have something like this?

mywebsite.com/**en**/ => mywebsite.com/**?lang=en**

mywebsite.com/**en**/about => mywebsite.com/about/**?lang=en**

mywebsite.com/**en**/search/?query=Hello+World => mywebsite.com/search/**?query=Hello+World&lang=en**

so in the reality my files are like:

```
public_html/about/index.php
public_html/search/index.php
public_html/index.php
```

but i m faking it like

```
public_html/en/about/index.php
public_html/en/search/index.php
public_html/en/index.php
```

and need to conserve the URL, and PARAMETERS passed through GET, i don't understand how to setup a so complex url controller in .htaccess

i've also tried following this but not getting out, is there any sample project?
[cakephp 3 parameter url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609022/cakephp-3-parameter-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you rearrange the request URL. This means, you must capture `(...)` the parts separately, and put them together in the substitution `$...`. You also want to keep an existing query string, which requires the use of the [`QSA|qsappend`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag. The `RewriteCond` is there to prevent a rewrite loop. If the rule was applied once, it shouldn't be used a second time.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=
RewriteRule ^(..)(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To learn more about regular expressions, see [Apache - Regular Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Comment: I don't know why with QSA the server printss error 500, and it's continuesly redirecting to the **HIDDEN** target `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^lang-(.*+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]`, with this line i got a little bit more near, but i m still far from the page url. for a link like this `/lang-EN/aboutus/?article=0` it var_dumps `array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(11) "EN/aboutus/" }`; while if instead of ? i use & it var_dumps `array(2) { ["lang"]=> string(11) "EN/aboutus/" ["article"]=> string(1) "0" }`now i must be able to extract aboutus from the $_GET['lang'] and put it at the place of index.php

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault, I missed to check for the rewrite loop. Please see updated answer.